# Correcting 'bad' translations in a sequence-to-sequence neural machine translation model

Tags: machine-learning, models

In working with basic [sequence-to-sequence models for machine translation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/) I have been able to achieve decent results. But inevitably some translations are not optimal or just flat-out incorrect. I am wondering if there is some way of "correcting" the model when it makes mistakes while not compromising the desirable behavior on translations where it previously performed well.

As an experiment, I took a model that I had previously trained and gathered several examples of translations where it performed poorly. I then took those examples and put them into their own small training set where I provided more desirable translations than what the model was outputting. I then trained the old model on this new small training set very briefly (3-6 training steps was all it took to "learn" the new material). When I tested the new model it translated those several examples in the exact way I had specified. But as I should have anticipated the model overcompensated to "memorize" those handful of new examples  and thus I noticed it started to perform poorly on translations that it had previously been excellent.

Is there some way to avoid this behavior short of simply retraining the model from scratch on an updated data set? I think I understand intuitively that the nature of neural networks would not lend itself to small precise corrections (i.e. when the weighting of just a few neurons change the performance of the entire model will change) but maybe there is a way around it, perhaps with some type of hybrid reinforcement learning approach.

**Update:**

This [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W15-4006) speaks of approaches to incrementally improving neural machine translation models

Answer (score 0):

The basic process you're describing sounds a lot like [Boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), which is also well covered in Chapter 18 of [Russell & Norvig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136042597), or like [active learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)).

You're correct that training the model with emphasis on a specific subset of the data is likely to lead to mistakes somewhere else. Boosting gets around this in a clever way.

1. It begins by training a model as normal.
2. The new model's performance on the training set is measured.
3. A new dataset is generated, where examples that were misclassified by the previous model are more highly weighted (this is intuitively similar to adding an extra copy of them to the dataset).
4. A new model is trained on the weighted dataset. The model suffers a greater penalty for making the same kinds of errors as the previous model(s), and so tends to make different errors.
5. Steps 2-4 are repeated for some time.
6. An *ensemble* of models is output, rather than a single model.

To classify new points, the most common score from all ensemble members is used.

I'm less familiar with NLP work using this approach, but it seems like the same basic idea could be used fruitfully here: the notion is to train many models that make independent errors, and then trust their collective decisions.